# mapreduce program not producing the requied output in distributed mode

Tags: hadoop, maps, mapreduce

I need some help in my map-reduce code.
The code run's perfectly in eclipse and in standalone mode, but when i package the code and try running it locally on pseudo distributed mode, the output is not as i expect.

```
Map input records = 11
Map input records = 11

Reduce input records = 11
Reduce output records = 0
```

These are the values i get.

where as when i run the same code in eclipse or in standalone mode with same config & input file

```
Map input records = 11
Map output records = 11

Reduce input records = 11
Reduce output records = 4
```

Can any one tell me whats wrong..??

i tried both the ways of building .jar file for eclipse -> export -> runable jar and form terminal as well(javac -classpath hadoop-core-1.0.4 -d classes mapredcode.java && jar -cvf mapredcode.jar -C classes/ .)

and how do i debug this..

Comment: Why don't you try sysouting the values in different places of the Reducer class. At least you'll know where you are missing the data.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a `combiner()` method?
And if yes. then is the o/p of combiner the same as that of the mapper?

Because in Hadoop, Combiner is run at the disposal of Hadoop itself and may not be running in the pseudo-disrtibuted mode in your case.
The combiner in itself is nothing but a reducer that is used to lower the network traffic.

And the code should be such that even if a Combiner is not running, the reducer should get the expected format from the mapper.

Hope it helps.